# to add column values in a specific manner in a csv file using python

Tags: python, csv

i have a csv file similar to the following :

```
title  title2  h1  h2  h3 ... 
l1.1     l1     1   1   0  
l1.2     l1     0   1   0
l1.3     l1     1   0   1
l2.1     l2     0   0   1
l2.2     l2     1   0   1
l3.1     l3     0   1   1
l3.2     l3     1   1   0
l3.3     l3     1   1   0
l3.4     l3     1   1   0
```

i want to be able to add the columns in the following manner:
h1 ( l1.1 + l1.2+ l1.3 ) = 2
h1 ( l2.1 + l2.2 ) = 1
h1 ( l3.1 + l3.2 + l3.3 +l3.4) = 3 and so on for every column
And i want the final count for every such value as a summarised table :

```
title2  h1  h2  h3...
l1     2   2   1
l2     1   0   2
l3     3   4   1
```

how do i implement this?

Comment: That's not a csv, there are no commas! ;)

Comment: well it does not appear with commas in excel... and csv does not necessarily mean comma separated.. it can be tab seprarated also...

Comment: @newbie: no one is interested in your deadline. Stop fiddling with tags, thanks.

Comment: Why not simply build a PivotTable in Excel? That's exactly what they're for.

Comment: but is this technically feasible in python??

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work. It takes an input in the form

```
title,title2,h1,h2,h3
l1.1,l1,1,1,0
l1.2,l1,0,1,0
l1.3,l1,1,0,1
l2.1,l2,0,0,1
l2.2,l2,1,0,1
l3.1,l3,0,1,1
l3.2,l3,1,1,0
l3.3,l3,1,1,0
l3.4,l3,1,1,0
```

and outputs

```
title2,h1,h2,h3
l1,2,2,1
l2,1,0,2
l3,3,4,1
```

Tested with Python 3.1.2. In Python 2.x you'll need to change the `open()` calls to use binary mode, and drop the `newline=""` bit). You can also drop the call to `list()` since in Python 2.x, `map()` already returns a list.

```
import csv
import operator

reader = csv.reader(open("test.csv", newline=""), dialect="excel")
result = {}

for pos, entry in enumerate(reader):
    if pos == 0:
        headers = entry
    else:
        if entry[1] in result:
            result[entry[1]] = list(map(operator.add, result[entry[1]], [int(i) for i in entry[2:]]))
        else:
            result[entry[1]] = [int(i) for i in entry[2:]]

writer = csv.writer(open("output.txt", "w", newline=""), dialect="excel")
writer.writerow(headers[1:])

keys = sorted(result.keys())
for key in keys:
    output = [key]
    output.extend(result[key])
    writer.writerow(output)
```

Comment: i m using python 2.7... i ve changed the open() part to "open('test.csv','rb'))... but i am getting a syntax error with the "result[entry[1]] = list(map(operator.add, result[entry[1]], [int(i) for i in entry[2:]]))"        line12.... any modification i might have to make??

Comment: Ah yes, remove the `list()`, that's only needed in Python 3 since `map` returns a view instead of a list in Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the csv module. What you want to do is open the file with a csv.reader. Then you iterate over the file, one row at the time. You accumulate the results of the additions into a temporary list. When you are done, you write this list to a new csv.writer.

You might need to define a dialect as you are not really using CSV but some tab-delimited format.

Comment: even if i read one row at a time, how do i accumulate the results for l1 alone, l2 alone and so on.... and this is necessarily comma separated i ve just given the table like this for better understanding..

Comment: I can, but I won't. Accumulation is basic programming practice.

Comment: i ve done some editing to the above table... i have now managed to get it in the above format... will this help??

Comment: can you atleast give me more instructions on how to do this... i really can't get the hang of it...

Comment: i don't mean to read it row wise... i want to read it column wise... can this be done by comparing title2 column's data?